# mod_deflate emulation using PHP

Tags: php, gzip, deflate

For some reasons I CAN'T use mod_deflate or mod_gzip on my server. So I'm trying to implement mod_deflate using PHP.

Here is my code:

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents($filename);
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filename));
echo gzcompress($filecontents);
```

But for some reason I get ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in browser. Browser supports gzip.
What can cause this problem?

Comment: `What can cause this problem?` - Maybe [chunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)?

Comment: So, there is no way to disable chunking, so people advise to specify Content-Length. I tried header('Content-Length:'.strlen($filecontents)) but this doesn't work.

Comment: Just make a raw HTTP request using something like telnet or netcat and the problem should become pretty visible.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 20:12:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1965
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

So, what's the problem?

Comment: That depends on whether or not there is any content beyond the headers you've shown.

Comment: I figured out. I don't know why but gzencode($contents, 9, FORCE_GZIP) is working fine and gzencode($contents, 9, FORCE_DEFLATE) is not.